# session_regenerate_id() behaves differently in PHP 7 from PHP 5 by closing session too early

Tags: php, session

I have an application running under PHP 5.4 that saves session data to the database using the `session_set_save_handler()` function. The "close" callable in my custom session handler looks something like this:

```
public function close()
{
    return $this->dbConnection->close();
}
```

My understanding is that close() will be called after PHP has finished writing to the session, and therefore that the database connection will also be closed at that point. I have seen other examples where people **do not** close the database connection inside the close() callable, but that's what my application currently does.

In my login script I also call `session_regenerate_id(TRUE)` to change the session ID. This works fine in PHP 5.4 and does not appear to close the database connection as soon as the function has been called, but upon upgrading to PHP 7.4 the database connection is automatically closed as soon as the function is called, so the application fails at that stage. There is code later on in the same script that writes to the session after the script has validated the user's login credentials, so the database connection needs to be active.

What is the expected (or correct) behaviour? Was the implementation wrong in PHP 5.4 (and earlier versions) and `session_regenerate_id(TRUE)` should have closed the session but didn't, or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for any input/comments.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the source for this?

Comment: No not yet, but that's a good suggestion.

Comment: In PHP 7.4, there were changes in the way sessions are handled, which could explain the behavior you're observing. The call to session_regenerate_id(TRUE) in PHP 7.4 might be causing an implicit session close operation, which in turn calls your close() function, closing the database connection prematurely.

Comment: Comparing the current version of ext/session/session.c with an older version form 2014, it looks session_regenerate_id() always explicity closes the session before re-opening it, creating a new session ID and reading the session. I can't see any specific code related to closing the session in the older version.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php#119418, there's also the red warning about needing to forcing of close sessions. A tiny discussion is available here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71394, I'm pretty sure this is it and was intentional. There's also this RFC https://wiki.php.net/rfc/precise_session_management which provides a good look into how sessions should behave. The `close` method of your custom handler closes the database connection. This is a bad side-effect. The close method is used to unlock file locks, release FDs and such to prevent race conditions.

Comment: You should not be closing a shared database connection in your session `close` method. You can only do this if you actually open a dedicated one in your `open` method. Overall, closing database connections is not a session handler's responsibility. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and links. The fact that my code closes the database connection inside the close() callable wasn't a concious design decision, it was probably just as a result of me copying an online example when I had to rewrite the code to migrate from the old mysql() functions. If PHP 5.4 worked as PHP 7 does now I would have realised my design was wrong. I'm intending to rewrite the custom session handler using the newer interface method. I also need to look at whether session_regenerate_id(TRUE) is still correct because of the warning about the potential exploit/race condition.